# Whether to close or delete one's own question

Tags: discussion

If you ask a question which is the result of a misreading, typo or some other triviality and someone posts an answer, what is the best course of action?

If the help came in the form of a comment I would just delete the question. But because there is now an accepted answer I've just voted to close my question instead. The system warns me that deleting questions with answers is bad. Does the answerer lose their rep if the question is deleted? Are there any other good reasons why it would be bad in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deletion of an answer undoes all reputation points — for each upvote the answerer loses 10 points and for each downvote the answerer gains 2 points and each downvoter gains 1 point.

If the question is off-topic, the question should be closed, but I don't think it needs to be deleted — it may be helpful to someone at some point. Especially if there is an upvoted answer, I would by default not delete the question. The question can continue garnering upvotes if it was particular well-written question, or if it triggered a useful answer. If neither question nor answer are helpful (i.e. are not garnering enough votes) the question and the answer will be auto-deleted at some point (see [Deletion of answers to off-topic questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1820/1628)), another reason why you might just leave it up to the system to decide if it should be deleted at some point.